# How to rename file while using express fileupload in node.js

Tags: node.js, file

I have file upload functionality and I am using `express-fileupload` module in node.js to upload file to local folder. I am explaining my existing code below.

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));
const avatar = req.files.file;
avatar.mv('./uploads/' + avatar.name);
```

Here I can upload the file to my upload folder but here I need to add the `timestamp` with the file name and then upload so that I can differentiate if any new file is coming with same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code may help you

```
const path = require('path');

let target_file = req.files.target_file;

var file_name = new Date().getTime() +'_'+target_file.name;

// target_file.mv(path, callback)
target_file.mv(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', file_name), (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
      res.send('File Uploaded');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code(by Elangovan Selvaraj) before this comment is absolutely correct.

I tried with:

```
const pdfUpload = req.files.documents;

const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '_' + pdfUpload.name;

const pdfPath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        '../public/uploads/hotels/kyc/' + `${fileName}`
      );

await pdfUpload.mv(pdfPath);
```